# How can I get control panel display setting on python?

Tags: python, windows

[image]

I want to get display setting value on python like:

100% or 125% or 150%

How can I get this set value on python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings window that you want to access is generally this `C:\Windows\System32\DpiScaling.exe` executable.

So now you can access this executable by using python. There might be many different ways to do so. In my example I am using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) module.

**Code:**

```
import subprocess

def openSettings():
    subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Windows\System32\DpiScaling.exe"])

openSettings()
```

Comment: This might help http://superuser.com/questions/759498/dpi-scaling-in-windows-8-1-via-command-line